# How to replace string with certificate string in json file shell

Tags: string, shell, sed, replace

I'm trying to replace get the content of a `crt` file and replace string in json file with the retrieved crt content, here's what I have done:

## Content of cert file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

## Content of template.json file:

```
{
  "cert": "CERT"
}
```

## test.sh

```sh
# Fetching cert.crt content and storing in CERT variable
CERT=$(cat cert.crt)

# Converting cert to single line string by replacing newline with \n
CERT=$(echo "${CERT//$'\n'/\n}")

# Trying to replace CERT string in template.json and store the updated json in test.json
sed -e "s/_CERT_/${CERT}/g" template.json > test.json
```

I'm getting the following error while running the script:

```
sed: 1: "s/ORDERER_CA_CERT/----- ...": bad flag in substitute command: 't'
```

## Expected output

```
{
  "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJYCvxDO8/AIgIj2J6hOpgXxbeuO9kF+srpkwKE8Z1/5Efwd73nMcsvo=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

Comment: @anubhava I have added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternate delimiter in `sed` as `/` is used in cert data:

```
cert=$(<cert.crt)
cert="${cert//$'\n'/\\\\n}"

sed "s~\"CERT\"~\"$cert\"~" template.json
```

Use `\\\\n` in replacement to get single `\n` in output.

```
{
  "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJYCvxDO8/AIgIj2J6hOpgXxbeuO9kF+srpkwKE8Z1/5Efwd73nMcsvo=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

---

Here is one-liner solution using `awk`:

```
awk -v cert="$(<cert.crt)" 'BEGIN{gsub(/\n/, "\\n", cert)}
{sub(/"CERT"/, "\"" cert "\"")} 1' template.json
```

Comment: In the output, there's no slash before `n`, It should have been `\n` instead just `n`

Comment: can you also provide a single liner solution for this, that would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: single line solution not working, It's printing these lines:

```awk: newline in string -----BEGIN CERTIFICA... at source line 1
awk: newline in string -----BEGIN CERTIFICA... at source line 1
awk: newline in string -----BEGIN CERTIFICA... at source line 1```

Comment: That requires `gnu-awk`. On BSD awk use this: `awk 'FNR == NR {s = (s == "" ? $0 : s "\\n" $0); next} {sub(/"CERT"/, "\"" s "\"")} 1' cert.crt template.json`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was all I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a safe way of doing this directly in `jq`:

```
$ echo '{}' | jq --arg cert "$(<cert.crt)" '{"cert": $cert}'
{
  "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJYCvxDO8/AIgIj2J6hOpgXxbeuO9kF+srpkwKE8Z1/5Efwd73nMcsvo=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a solution without installing `jq`.